# Saving data from option value to local storage

Tags: jquery

I have been looking something likes this but I can't find anything that would help me with this 
Im trying to make a small bot that will press e for me in a game. I have a menu that looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhV5A.png. Now the problem that im having is saving the data so if I change it from OFF to ON and I refresh the website then it goes back to OFF and I have tried a few things to store the data but all of them failed.

The code:

The values that im trying to save are mbot, sbot, zbot

```
    // ZMIENNE //
var mbot="OFF";
var sbot="OFF";
var zbot="OFF";

var zabitem=0;

setInterval(function() {
    mbot=$("#atakbot").val();
    sbot=$("#strzalabot").val();
    zbot=$("#zlotobot").val();
}, 1000);



setInterval( function() {
    if (mbot === "ON") {
        for(var i in g.npc){
            if ((Math.abs(hero.rx - g.npc[i].x) <= 1 && Math.abs(hero.ry - g.npc[i].y) <= 1) && (g.npc[i].type == 2 || g.npc[i].type == 3)){
                _g("fight&a=attack&id=-"+i);
                $("#autobattleButton").remove();
                setTimeout('_g("fight&a=f");',1000);
                zabitem+=1;
                break;
            }
        }}
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
    if (mbot === "ON") {
        $("#a_ok").click();
    }
}, 10000);


setInterval( function() {
    if (sbot === "ON") {
        var SOK = false;
        var OK2=1;
        var Sitem = false;
            if (OK2===1) {
                SOK = false;
                for(var i in g.item){
                    Sitem = $("#item"+i);
                    if(g.item[i].cl == 21 && Sitem.css("top") == "183px" && Sitem.css("left") == "92px"){
                        var Sstat = g.item[i].stat;
                        var Sname = g.item[i].name;
                        var Sid = g.item[i].id;
                        SOK = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(SOK){
                    var SnumAmmo = Sstat.indexOf("ammo");
                    var Sammo = 51;
                    if(SnumAmmo != -1){
                        Sammo = Sstat.slice(SnumAmmo+5,SnumAmmo+9);
                        Sammo = parseInt(Sammo);
                    }
                    if(Sammo < 50){
                        for(var i in g.item){
                            if(Sname == g.item[i].name && Sid != g.item[i].id){
                                _g("moveitem&st=1&id="+g.item[i].id);
                                message("<font color='#00CC99'><b><center>Strzaly zmienione</center></b></font>");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}, 1000);



setInterval(function () {
    if (zbot === "1") {
        for (k in g.item) if ((g.item[k].loc=="g") && (g.item[k].stat.search("gold")>-1)) _g("moveitem&st=1&id=" + k);
    }
}, 1000);
```

EDIT 1: The solution to this is this

```
$(function() {
    $('#atakbot').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('atakbot', this.value);
    });
    if(localStorage.getItem('atakbot')){
        $('#atakbot').val(localStorage.getItem('atakbot'));
    }
});

$(function() {
    $('#strzalabot').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('strzalabot', this.value);
    });
    if(localStorage.getItem('strzalabot')){
        $('#strzalabot').val(localStorage.getItem('strzalabot'));
    }
});

$(function() {
    $('#zlotobot').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('zlotobot', this.value);
    });
    if(localStorage.getItem('zlotobot')){
        $('#zlotobot').val(localStorage.getItem('zlotobot'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Your don't need all those DOM ready wrappers. Only one.

Answer (score 0):

When getting, get it immediately with fallback value like:

```
var mbot = localStorage.mbot || "OFF";
```

which means use `localStorage.mbot` or fallback to `"OFF"`.
Setting is also quite straightforward:

```
$('#atakbot').on("change", function() {
    mbot = localStorage.mbot = this.value;
});
```

---

I've seen you're letting random `setIntervals` run uselessly in your code. Even if those run every 1000ms, which is not a performance killer, it's good habit to use **events** instead.

Comment: What event would i use instead of setIntervals?